# Using Lambda in shared internet gateway for siloed tenants

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function that I want to provide access to using a siloed tenant model (i.e. no shared resources so one Lambda instance per tenant) as we have quite strict data compliance requirements.

I need to have a static IP address for my Lambda function in order to access external SFTP servers and I followed [Generate a static outbound IP address using a Lambda function, Amazon VPC, and a serverless architecture - AWS Prescriptive Guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html) to set it up.

My question is: Do I need to create a new private/public subnet for every Lambda instance I have in order to maintain my tenant isolation? Or are there any resources of that setup that can be shared?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to have a separate public IP address for the external SFTP servers? Can't you use the same one, since clearly the traffic is coming from "you"? If you need a separate IP addresses for each client, you'll need a separate NAT Gateway for each client (~$400/year).

Comment: I'd say this all depends on your tenants' requirements for isolation or any compliance requirements that you might have to meet. You might need/prefer AWS account-level isolation or VPC-level isolation, for example. Be aware of [Serverless SaaS](https://aws.amazon.com/partners/programs/saas-factory/serverless-saas/) as it may provide some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each Lambda function to have a different public IP address, you would need:

- A separate private subnet and Route Table
- A separate Lambda function
- A separate NAT Gateway

It might be possible to launch multiple NAT Gateways in the same public subnet, but I haven't tried it myself. There is no cost for a public subnet itself, so you might want to use separate public subnets to match the private subnets. They could all be quite small (eg `/28` = 16 addresses).

Each private subnet would have a different Route Table that points to a different NAT Gateway.

Please note that NAT Gateways are charged at $0.045c/hour, so it would have a cost of ~$400/year per NAT Gateway, plus traffic charges.

Comment: Correct, I don't actually need a separate IP address per client. I don't have in-depth knowledge of network configuration so I was trying to find the most cost-efficient (and labour efficient :) ) way of setting up different Lambda instances.

So if I re-use the same IP but want to keep the isolation, I should create separate subnets for each tenant but use the same NAT Gateway?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "isolation". If the Lambda function is the only resource in a VPC, then there's nothing to isolate from a network perspective -- a single private subnet for all Lambda functions would be fine since Lambda functions don't allow incoming connections, and you can share a single NAT Gateway. However, you would want to use **separate Lambda functions** for each tenant because Lambda execution environments can be reused and information could be stored in memory or in `/tmp/`.

Comment: If you want to learn how Lambda functions operate, I highly recommend this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: To be more specific the Lambda function I have is pulling customer files down from an SFTP server and pushing them to another service. I want to avoid any possibility of data leaking between tenants. Which is why I was using the "one lambda instance" per tenant.  In order to use a static IP I need to configure it to use the VPC set up in the link from the original post. So you think the subnet / NAT could be shared in that scenario?

Comment: Yes. If your Lambda function is only storing data locally (not in S3), then just make sure that it is a "different AWS Lambda function" and nothing will be shared between them. This means each tenant would have their own (separate) Lambda function  shown in the AWS Lambda management console. The term 'instance' doesn't really apply to Lambda functions -- when invoked, Lambda functions are provisioned in 'containers' or 'environments'. One Lambda function could give rise to multiple containers if called in high volume. Containers belong to only one Lambda function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations John, you have been super helpful!